# How to Show sweet alert in partial view when model is NOT valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, sweetalert

I'm working with mvc 5.
in popup partial view , user fill textboxes and for example if, barcode is exist, must be back in partial view and show warning with sweet alert.
i use viewbag and tempdata to fill sweet alert comment.
part of partial :

```
      <script>
    $(function() {
        var a = '@TempData["Message"]';
        if (a != '')
            swal({ title: "Done", text: "@TempData["Message"]", icon: "success" });

    });
</script>
```

controller:

```
 var exist = _department.Where(x => x.deptName == model.DepartmentName && x.deptCode == model.Code);
        if (exist!=null)
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Code or Name is exist!!!";
            return View("_CreateDepartmentPartial", model);
        }
```

this method works in normal view ! but in popup partial view not working!!
thanks.

Comment: Are you doing an ajax form submit ? If yes, call sweetalert in the success handler.

Comment: Yes i do. could you please tell me how to do this with success handler? thanks @Shyju

Comment: Share the relevant part of your ajax code and the action method which handles the ajax form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TempData["Message"]` is not the right way to pass data from `controller` to any `views`

You need to use either `ViewBag` or `ViewData` - `TempData` is all about passing value from one action method to another

Try something like this

**Controller**

```
var exist = _department.Where(x => x.deptName == model.DepartmentName && x.deptCode == model.Code);
        if (exist!=null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Code or Name is exist!!!";
            return View("_CreateDepartmentPartial", model);
        }
```

You can read the `ViewBag.Message` in your `script` section

Hope this works - Happy coding :)

Comment: Hi. unfortunately not working with viewbag - viewdata , i think the problem is the way i'm sending data to partial view opened in popup modal! thanks @ Rahul Swamynathan

Comment: Add your view and controller code completely - let me run and check from my end

Comment: i can't do this because a lot of codes are in the PartialView. i think this issue is from controller. cant sent any variable to partial view popup. even a smiple Viewbag! @Rahul Swamynathan

Comment: For alert you are using a view if so it's not necessary - if not try one this try to just change the result as `return PartialView()`

Comment: Oh no problem, i changed my solution and used jquery ajax validation! thanks by the way, ;) @Rahul Swamynathan